# Why sed command not working in GitHub Action?

Tags: sed, github-actions

I have this `yaml` file for a `Cloud Run config` with the following placeholders:

1. REGION
2. SERVICE_ACCOUNT
3. IMAGE
4. PROJECT_ID

```yaml
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tickets
  labels:
    cloud.googleapis.com/location: REGION
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: SERVICE_ACCOUNT
      containers:
        - image: IMAGE
          args:
            - -firebase-project-id=PROJECT_ID
            - -env=development
```

I also have a job defined for GitHub Actions:

```yaml
# This workflow will deploy the built container image from Artifact Registry to Cloud Run.

name: Deploy to Cloud Run

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      version:
        description: "The version to deploy"
        required: true

jobs:
  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: "read"
      id-token: "write"

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Google Auth
        uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v1"
        with:
          token_format: "access_token"
          workload_identity_provider: "${{ secrets.WIF_PROVIDER }}" # e.g. - projects/123456789/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my-pool/providers/my-provider
          service_account: "${{ secrets.WIF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}" # e.g. - my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com

      - name: Replace values in the YAML file
        env:
          REGION: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_REGION }}
          SERVICE_ACCOUNT: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
          IMAGE: ${{ secrets.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }}/ticketing-dev/tickets:${{ github.sha }}
          PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }}
        run: |
          sed -i.bak "s/REGION/$REGION/g" cloud-run.yml
          sed -i.bak "s/SERVICE_ACCOUNT/$SERVICE_ACCOUNT/g" cloud-run.yml
          sed -i.bak "s/IMAGE/$IMAGE/g" cloud-run.yml
          sed -i.bak "s/PROJECT_ID/$PROJECT_ID/g" cloud-run.yml

      - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v1
        with:
          metadata: ./cloud-run.yml

      - name: Show Cloud Run URL
        run: echo ${{ steps.deploy.outputs.url }}
```

At the `Replace values in YAML file` step I try to use the sed command to replace those placeholders from the `Cloud run config` file.

**WHEN I RUN THE JOB I GET THIS ERROR:**

```
Run sed -i.bak "s/REGION/$REGION/g" cloud-run.yml
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unknown option to `s'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

And this error is not just for the `REGION` replace. He is the first that the sed command tries to replace...

I've also tried to use for eg. the actual value of the $REGION var in the sed command and not use the env variable and still, it didn't work...

It works only if I do something like this:

```
sed -i 's/REGION/<value>/g` cloud-run.yaml
```

but for my case I need to use double quotes "" to replace with the value of the variable $REGION...

Comment: Maybe interpolation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/319826

Comment: Why not use a [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) instead of sed?

Answer (score 0):

1. Escape '/' in the IMAGE variable
2. Run one sed command with multiple expressions

```yaml
  - name: Replace values in YAML file
        env:
          REGION: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_REGION }}
          SERVICE_ACCOUNT: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
          IMAGE: ${{ secrets.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev\/${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }}\/ticketing-dev\/tickets:${{ github.sha }}
          PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }}
        run: sed -e "s/REGION/$REGION/g" -e "s/SERVICE_ACCOUNT/$SERVICE_ACCOUNT/g" -e "s/IMAGE/$IMAGE/g" -e "s/PROJECT_ID/$PROJECT_ID/g" cloud-run.yml
```